# Accidentally "Removed Attachments" via Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, attachments

I was trying to clear up space on my HD by running "Remove Attachments" in Mail.app on my Gmail accounts.

Too late I realized this deleted the attachments from server (Gmail) as well. They all show "[The attachment ___ has been manually removed]".

Now I see I should have just deleted locally from my HD, but is there any way to recover these attachments? Are they still on Gmail somewhere?

Comment: Are they gone from the Trash folder in gMail?

Comment: @fbara They were never "sent to trash" ... they have just had their attachments deleted, and are still where they were prior.

Comment: To clarify, the email is still on gMail, when you login directly there and not from Mail, but the attachment has been removed and the attachment isn't in the gMail Trash folder?  It's also not in the Mac's Trash?  I just want to be sure I understand your problem and what you've already done to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, precisely. The messages have been "modified" so that they no longer include the attachments, and have had the text I mentioned above appended. Same on Gmail & in Mail. Nothing in either Trash.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that does help with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I have just accidentally "manually removed attachments" from Mac mail and because I had opened them first (word documents) I was able to open Word and go to "open recent" and they did open and I was able to save them properly.  Just as well because I had been unable to find them in the files that were modified today.